# Attemping to read specific Excel sheets with apache poi

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

Does anyone knows if I can specify the name(s) of the sheets that I want to read using Apache Poi?

Right now I'm using a *for* to read all sheets in a workbook.

Comment: To you read with event model or not? What is the code you got?

Comment: No @RobertRossmann, it is just a question if it possible or not to do what I'm asking with Apache Poi. If not to do it with another library.

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau I don't have a code yet, but I  would like to know if it's possible with Apache Poi to do so. Right know I'm using a for to read every sheet.

Comment: The point was, you should do some research before asking a question. Your question does not show any amount of effort. [See how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: If someone answers yes is possible, I take care of what goes next. That's all. I'm searching for information in the web, but an answer yes or no could save me a lot of time and help me a lot. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so to answer the question and save you a lot of time...

Yes, it is possible and can be easily done via `getSheet(java.lang.String name)` on the `org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook`.

As a side note I'd strongly suggest going through [POI Busy Developers' Guide](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html) and the [API documentation](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Workbook.html), as it's a really powerful library which familiarity with can save you a lot of time in the future.

Comment: Sure, if it answers your question please approve it.